# Java get digits from a number in reverse order - cannot use arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I am trying to do an assignment for my Java class. I am very confused at how I am supposed to perform this without using arrays. The problem to be solved is: The user inputs an integer, each number within the integer is converted to its word form, but the output is in reverse order. Example:

Input: 1080

Output: Zero Eight Zero One

Input: -542

Output: Minus Two Four Five

The thing that makes it really difficult for me to understand is trying to find out how to do this without using arrays of any kind. Converting individual numbers to words is just a simple switch statement, but how do you go about reading the input and separating each number within the larger number? How do you rearrange them to be in reverse order?

I'm not looking for the entire answer! I just don't understand how to do this without arrays. Everything I search for on the internet comes up with using arrays.

EDIT: This is a BEGINNER Java class, guys. Haters gonna hate...

Comment: Ask your TA, or try 'ArrayList'.

Comment: ArrayList is backed by an array.

Comment: Not sure why everyone is recommending data structures. There's a trivial way to get one digit at a time from low to high.

Comment: Well you need at least to use `String#charAt(index)` and iterate backward, i.e from `str.length()-1` till `0`. This of course if the number is represented as String, if it is an integer then refer to @rolfl 's answer.

Comment: @ZouZou So are strings. So the OP can't use strings now?

Comment: Hint: `1080 = 1*10^3 + 0*10^2 + 8*10^1 + 0*10^0`. `^` meaning `pow`, of course.

Comment: @hexafraction Sure Strings are also backed by arrays, but I think you understood what I would mean by that. If you can't use an array to sort, why could you use an ArrayList ?

Comment: I don't understand why this question received downvotes.  Even if it is basic java, it shows research effort, and is clear and useful.

Comment: @MrTi I don't know for sure, but it's likely because no attempts were provided and it was blatantly stated as homework

Comment: @Zeaklous The first point is valid...However, while the homework tag has been removed, I've never heard anything about homework help not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MrTi I wasn't one who downvoted, simply philosophized. I didn't upvote it because it didn't provide attempts though

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo and division mechanisms .....

```
if (input < 0) {
   // output 'minus'
   // change it to positiv
   input = -input;
}
while (input > 0) {
    int digit = input % 10;
    // output the digit
    // remove the last digit
    input = input / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The class I am taking is a BEGINNER Java class. So if the answer is trivial I didn't know that. :C no need for everyone to show so much hate, sorry for asking a question!

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a function that takes a number as an input, uses a for loop with `str.length-1` that iterates through each number starting with the last, obtain the integer itself using `str.charAt(i)` and as you said use a switch statement to turn the number into a String. Then you can compile them using the `+=` operator

Something like this should work

```
String numberSentence (int input) {
    String total = new String();
    String inputS = input.toString();
    int min = 0;
    if(inputS.charAt(0) == '-'){
      total.concat("Minus ")
      min = 1;
    }
    for(int i = inputS.length-1; i >= min; i--) {
        total.concat(stringify(inputS.charAt(i)));
    }
    return total.toString();
}
String stringify (String letter) {
    String word;
    switch(letter) {
        case "1": word = "one"; // Don't forget the "" !
                  break;
        ... Continued ...
    }
    return word;
}
```

This same approach can be used when the input is not an `int`